# Use Java constant in GWT Javascript Overlay Type (JSO)?

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.4

I would like to define the GWT [JSO](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html) property name as a constant in the JSO, in order to avoid typos and benefit from Eclipse code completion, like so:

```java
public final class MyJSO extends JavaScriptObject
{
    /** here is the constant */
    private static final String MY_CONST = "myPropName";

    protected MyJSO() {
        super();
    }

    public native void setMyProp(final boolean pFlag)
    /*-{
        this.@fully.qualified.MyJSO::MY_CONST = pFlag;
    }-*/;

    public native boolean isMyProp()
    /*-{
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(@fully.qualified.MyJSO::MY_CONST)) {
            return this.@fully.qualified.MyJSO::MY_CONST;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }-*/;
}
```

The GWT compiler should be able to replace the String from the constant at compile time, so there is no problem with the object living as Javascript later on.

But this is so totally not working, I'm thinking I may be wrong. :-) Can anyone explain why? Do you have better ideas how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [correct syntax](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#methods-fields) to refer to a static variable is:

```
@fully.qualified.MyJSO::MY_CONST
```

No qualifier (`this.`, in your example) is needed since the variable is static.

If you want to set/get a property on the JavaScript object with the constant name do so as follows:

```java
public native void setMyProp(final boolean pFlag) /*-{
    this[@fully.qualified.MyJSO::MY_CONST] = pFlag;
}-*/;

public native boolean isMyProp() /*-{
    if (this[@fully.qualified.MyJSO::MY_CONST] != null) {
        return this[@fully.qualified.MyJSO::MY_CONST];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}-*/;
```

Comment: Thanks! The hint that solved it was that I must use square brackets to access the property, not the dot notation. Using square brackets, my code works! The `hasOwnProperty` line can remain unchanged even.

Comment: If only SO knew [nested syntax highlighting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203205/205238) ... :-)